# Multiple SpringBoot apps with same data source

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have two spring boot application deployed on same tomcat and both application have same datasource.

```
I get InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx:name=dataSourceMBean,type=Co‌​nnectionPool .
```

I have already set

> endpoints.jmx.domain=myapp
>   endpoints.jmx.uniqueNames=true.

But I still get the error. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I could solve the problem.
```

> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/118

```
endpoints.jmx.domain=dev
endpoints.jmx.unique-names=true
spring.jmx.default-domain=dev
spring.application.name=dev





endpoints.jmx.domain=dev2
 endpoints.jmx.unique-names=true
 spring.jmx.default-domain=dev2
 spring.application.name=dev2
```